# My page generates multiple divs with same ID and same class. I want to print them all with the same javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, css

So far I managed to print only the first div while using the getElementById() option. However, since my page generates multiple divs with the same ID it is not possible to print them all with the same print function. I am looking into the getElementsByClassName() option, but I am not able to get it to print all of the generated divs on the page. So far I am getting the "undefined" option.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function printFunc() {
var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printableArea");
var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
    'table th, table td {' +
    'border:1px solid #000;' +
    'padding;0.5em;' +
    '}' +
    '</style>';
htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
newWin = window.open("");
newWin.document.write("<h3 align='center'>Print Page</h3>");
newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
}
```

Here is how I call it into the page:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Print" onclick="printFunc();">
```

The  I am trying to print is setup like:

```
<div id="printableAreaID">
<div class="printArea">
<table>
   Contents...
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

I should maybe mention that this is on Moodle 3.6.2, on a database activity where I have three separate fields to input CSS, javascript and any html I deem necesary, without the need of defining  Head and body tags.

Comment: “*my page generates multiple divs with the same ID*” This would be invalid HTML; you should really use IDs and classes as they were intended (unique element identification and grouped element categorization respectively). If you choose not to do so, you may find your page exhibits unexpected or undefined behavior.

Comment: It does generate them like that, and true - that is not proper HTML, however since it is php based, and locked within a separate container, it doesn't make any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a class instead of an id however you should be able to use document.querySelectorAll("") to get an array of all the elements with that query.

```
function click() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#printableArea");
  elements.forEach((divToPrint) => {
    // your code
  });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! So what you are saying is basically this: `function click() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#printableAreaID");
  elements.forEach((divToPrint) => {
    // your code
 
 function printFunc() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printableAreaID");
    var htmlToPrint = '' +
       //styling omitted
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write("<h3 align='center'></h3>");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
    }
  });
}`